# PHP Excel Reader for Hebrew RTL shows Gibberish Data

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have excel file in `.xls` format. The Headings are in **Hebrew** due to the software from where i am getting the file. While reading it using [PHP Excel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) Library, it gives me a Gibberish Output. 
[image: See attached image]

Can someone guide me on how to enable PHP Excel to read the columns in correct format?

Comment: How are you displaying it? In a browser? Is your webpage using UTF-8?

Comment: Change your collation type to utf-8-general-ci and store data after that..in MYSQL

Comment: @MarkBaker Reading via php excel, outputting in browser.

Comment: @Kunal Collation type for xls file? I am not inserting to DB, The issue is that excel file contains Hebrew text, which PHP Excel reads as shown in question.

Comment: And the charset for your webpage where your'e displaying this data?

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes with UTF-8 it does show the data correct, but how can i compare the data while reading, i tried 
if('צורה' == $cell->getValue())
But that does not fill the condition although the column name is 'צורה'

Comment: I honestly haven't a clue how you would compare; I've never worked with RTL languages other than providing the basic PHPExcel methods to work with the file structure

Comment: @MarkBaker So there is not way i can Read Hebrew Column Headings and compare them to my array where i have set Hebrew to English column mappings...
There must be a solution. The excel file is generated by a software and i have no control on that, so i get this template which must be imported.

Comment: I'm sure that there is, and PHPExcel is reading them as stored in the file; what I don't know is how to compare them.... have you considered that the characters might be reversed? Have you looked at what getValue() actually returns for the cell?